# Java: how to make field of names

Tags: java, field

Firstly sorry for my english.
I want to ask you how can I make field of names into which I can put/save name from user.
This was my try, but every time I ran it and user write his name the first name in field was replaced by user name. I hope you understand me.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] name = {"John","Nico","Sarah","Pablo","Micheal"};
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Write your name: ");
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        name[i] = s;
    }
    Arrays.sort(name);
    for (String s2 : name)
    {
        System.out.print(s2 + ", ");

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want to add names to your field without replacing the names you already have saved?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` is pointless. It only "loops" once.

Comment: You are updating the `name` array at index 0 by doing `name[i] = s;` where `i` is 0.

Comment: Is it that you only want to read the name of the user and then sort it along with others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] names = {"John", "Nico", "Sarah", "Pablo", "Micheal", ""};
System.out.print("Write your name: ");
String userName = scanner.nextLine();
names[names.length - 1] = userName;
System.out.println(Arrays
        .stream(names)
        .sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

This should return what you want.

An Array always has a fixed size. By typing:

```
String[] names = {"John", "Nico", "Sarah", "Pablo", "Micheal"};
```

You define the size of the Array to be 5. By adding the extra "" you can "reserve" a place for the user's name.

Using:

```
names[names.length - 1] = userName;
```

You replace "" by the user input, instead of replacing the first name, like in your solution.

Hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are initializing the array name[] with some values and then overwriting the values with the user inputs. If you want to just initialize the array then you can use array initialization syntax.

```
String[] name = new String[5];
```

Also in the for loop the condition  i < 1 is wrong. It should be i < name.length.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //String[] name = { "John", "Nico", "Sarah", "Pablo", "Micheal" };
        String[] name = new String[5];

        //for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Write your name: ");
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            name[i] = s;
        }
        Arrays.sort(name);
        for (String s2 : name) {
            System.out.print(s2 + ", ");

        }
    }
```